¿Se puede reducir el consumo de memoria al usar lavfi en ffplay haciendo overlay con decenas de medios?
Se busca generar una solución automatizada con estructura estilo programación de tv "al vuelo" (esto es obligatorio), donde se reproduzcan videos de forma secuencial, sin cortes, durante varias horas, seguido de eso, sobre esos videos, mostrar otros videos o imágenes, que funcionarían como comerciales, algunos de ellos con transparencias, permitiendo mostrar el contenido subyacente, junto a todo eso, mostrar el logotipo del canal y alguna información, como una pleca (como las tiras de información de los noticieros, las que se colocan en el borde inferior de la pantalla). Es importante resaltar que se generan diferentes "programaciones", eso lo resuelvo de mi lado de forma automatizada y no es parte del problema, pero más adelante en los scripts algo de esa información aparecerá, para que eso no genere confusiones.
Se está realizando una mezcla de medios en un script sh, en lo que definimos como "tiras de medios", pero se tienen límites que no se cumplen, y pienso que tiene que ver con el desconocimiento de ffmpeg. Principalmente el consumo de memoria es el problema. Explico con más detalle:

Las tiras de medios pueden ser continuas, con un medio de audio, video o imagen, que al terminar inmediatamente empiece el otro, o pueden no serlo, donde un medio inicie y termine en un momento determinado y otro medio se cargue "n" segundos o minutos después.
Se tienen tres "tiras" de medios, primaria (continua), secundaria (no continua) y terciaria (continua).
La capa secunadaria se sobrepone a la primaria y la terciara a las otras dos.
Los medios son de distintos formatos.
El conjunto a reproducir tiene duraciones de hasta 24 horas.

Actualmente se ha generado una solución usando ffplay, pero tiene los siguienes contras:

El consumo de memoria es muy alto.
Tarda algunos segundos en generar la mezcla, suficientes para no ser lo que busco.
Con el pasar del tiempo el audio se desfasa del video.
En las computadoras objetivo, el resultado que pueden reproducir es de máximo grupos de hasta 4 horas.

Finalmente se tienen limitantes:

Los equipos donde se reproducirían estás mezclas son pequeños, procesadores celeron, 4GB (pero con la posibilidad de aumentar a 8 o hasta 32, lo que no quiero), discos duros mecánicos y sin depender de acceso a internet.
Deben de usar linux, actualmente Debian en su versión estable.

La solución actual se realiza en un sh por un programa que automatiza el proceso, coloqué comentarios explicativos y algunas puntuaciones que sé que no son parte de la sintaxis de ffplay. Solo para acortar el código para ustedes.
COMMAND="\
movie="medio1.m4v",scale=1920:1080[m1];\
amovie="medio1.m4v"[mOut1];\

# muchos medios de diferentes formatos

movie="medioN.m4v",scale=1920:1080[mN];\
amovie="medioN.m4v"[mOutN];\

movie="publicidad1.mov",scale=1920:-1,fps=30,fps=30,setpts=PTS+139/TB[p1];\

# muchas publicidades de diferentes formatos

movie="publicidadN.mov",scale=1920:-1,fps=30,fps=30,setpts=PTS+139/TB[pN];\

movie="logotipo1.mov",scale=1920:-1,fps=30,fps=30,setpts=PTS+139/TB[l1];\

# muchos logotipos y plecas de diferentes formatos

movie="logotipoN.mov",scale=1920:-1,fps=30,fps=30,setpts=PTS+139/TB[lN];\

[mOut1]...[mOutN]concat=n=N:v=0:a=1[out1];\
[m1]...[mN]concat=n=N,fps=30,settb=1/30[tiraPrincipal];\
[tiraPrincipal][p1]overlay=0:0:enable=between(t\,139\,160):eof_action=pass[mix1];\
[mix1][p2]overlay=0:0:enable=between(t\,180\,201):eof_action=pass[mix2];\

# muchos overlay después

[mixN-1][pN]overlay=0:0:enable=between(t\,4207\,4228)[tiraSecundaria];\

[tiraSecundaria][l1]overlay=0:0:enable=between(t\,139\,160):eof_action=pass[mixLogo1];\
[mixLogo1][l2]overlay=0:0:enable=between(t\,180\,201):eof_action=pass[mixLogo2];\

# muchos overlay después

[mixLogoN-1][lN]overlay=0:0:enable=between(t\,4207\,4228)[tiraTerciaria]" # aquí ya no va la etiqueta, pero es por clarificar para ustedes
ffplay -loglevel 8 -autoexit -f lavfi $COMMAND -framedrop


Cabe aclarar que al hacer los overlay, cuando son videos la única forma que logré que algunos videos "rebeldes" iniciaran donde les toca era con "setpts=PTS+TIEMPO_DE_INICIO/TB" y para los overlay ":eof_action=pass".
Lo que busco lograr es lo siguiente:

Generar la programación "al vuelo", ya que es necesario tener la capacidad de modificarla, si es necesario, antes de que se reproduzca un medio determinado. Sé que en el estado actual eso no es posible.
No se de el desfase en el audio y el video.
El consumo de memoria no sea enorme.

¿Qué he hecho?:

He divido la programación en partes de menor tamaño, para reproducirla por bloque, pero incluso en bloques de 10 minutos, las máquinitas donde se reproduce muestran un "corte", menor a un segundo, pero que no es lo que se busca.
Generar un archivo de concatenación, que funcionó desde punto de vista del cosumo de memoria, pero solo para la tira principal, no he logrado hacer los overlay de las otras tiras, el filtro lavfi no me permite colocar más medios de entrada (aquí es donde mi ignorancia comienza).
Convertir todos los archivos posibles a un formato determiado (mp4) lo que mejora el consumo de memoria, pero genera el problema que primero se deben convertir los medios antes de usarlos, me gustaría ahorrarme ese paso, porque son muchos medios los que se usan por semana, más de 1000.

Palabras finales:
Realmente no soy experto en el uso de ffmpeg o de todos los formatos multimedia usados, llevo unos 3 meses en investigación y ésto es lo más que he logrado, porque cada formato nuevo genera nuevos desafios. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de generar una secuencia de medios que se carge antes de reproducirse y al momento de que termine, libere la memoria usada, como imagino que lo hace el filtro concat. Además la solución no tiene que ser exactamente como la presenté yo, puede ser que sea por partes, pero es importante que los "cortes" entre parte y parte no se noten casi.

cosas que puedes hacer:

Decode ahead y thread queue: Usar decode_ahead=1 y ajustar
thread_queue_size puede ayudar a optimizar la decodificación.

Trim innecesario: Utiliza el filtro trim para cargar solo los segmentos
de video que realmente necesitas mostrar.

Optimización de memoria: Considera usar -infbuf para mejorar el buffering Ajusta el formato
de pixel con -vf "format=yuv420p" Usa -threads 0 para permitir que
ffmpeg optimice el uso de hilos

Simplificación de la cadena de filtros:
Minimiza el número de escalados (scale) Usa setpts=PTS-STARTPTS
después de trim para normalizar timestamps

Alternativas a considerar:
Evalúa si puedes pre-renderizar algunos elementos Considera dividir
en múltiples procesos si es posible


Ejemplo:
1. Usar filtros de decode_ahead y thread_queue_size
COMMAND="\
movie='medio1.m4v':decode_ahead=1:thread_queue_size=512,scale=1920:1080[m1];\
amovie='medio1.m4v':thread_queue_size=512[mOut1];\

2. Usar el filtro trim para cargar solo los segmentos necesarios
movie='publicidad1.mov':decode_ahead=1,trim=139:160,scale=1920:-1,fps=30,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[p1];\

3. Considerar el uso de select para frames específicos en logos
movie='logotipo1.mov':decode_ahead=1,trim=139:160,select='between(t,139,160)',scale=1920:-1,fps=30,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[l1];\

4. Concatenación de audio optimizada
[mOut1]...[mOutN]concat=n=N:v=0:a=1[out1];\

5. Concatenación de video con buffer optimizado
[m1]...[mN]concat=n=N:v=1,fps=30,settb=1/30[tiraPrincipal];\

6. Overlays con timebase consistente y optimizado
[tiraPrincipal][p1]overlay=0:0:eof_action=pass[mix1];\
[mix1][p2]overlay=0:0:eof_action=pass[mix2];\

Continúa con otros overlays...
[mixLogoN-1][lN]overlay=0:0:eof_action=pass[out]"

7. Opciones adicionales de ffplay para optimización
ffplay -loglevel warning \
  -autoexit \
  -f lavfi \
  "$COMMAND" \
  -framedrop \
  -infbuf \
  -vf "format=yuv420p" \
  -threads 0


Muchas gracias, y perdona la demora en contestar. Traté con cada uno de tus consejos pero, desafortunadamente, el rendimiento mejoró, pero no mucho. En mi proyecto decidieron cambiar la manera de abordar el problema, así que ya no seguiré intentando.
De nuevo, muchas gracias.
